# Getting error on ubuntu server on ec2 instance with file mounting system

Tags: docker, ubuntu, amazon-ec2

I have set up ubuntu server on ec2. when i do docker-compose up i get this error

```
Failed to write all bytes for _bisect.so
fwrite: No space left on device
```

when i do `lsblk -f` i get the following

```
NAME    FSTYPE   LABEL           UUID                                 FSAVAIL FSUSE% MOUNTPOINT
loop0   squashfs                                                            0   100% /snap/amazon-ssm-agent/3552
loop1   squashfs                                                            0   100% /snap/core18/1988
loop2   squashfs                                                            0   100% /snap/lxd/19188
loop3   squashfs                                                            0   100% /snap/lxd/19647
loop4   squashfs                                                            0   100% /snap/snapd/11036
loop5   squashfs                                                            0   100% /snap/snapd/11107
xvda                                                                                 
└─xvda1 ext4     cloudimg-rootfs 7969d789-20ae-4f61-84ff-c0ac50e0dd19  146.8M    98% /
xvdf    ext4                     b9de0623-ac46-43ff-9f8a-d12f2c4183b0   27.9G     0% /newvolume
```

df-h gives me this

```
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/root       7.7G  4.3G  3.5G  56% /
devtmpfs        484M     0  484M   0% /dev
tmpfs           490M     0  490M   0% /dev/shm
tmpfs            98M  868K   98M   1% /run
tmpfs           5.0M     0  5.0M   0% /run/lock
tmpfs           490M     0  490M   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
/dev/xvdf        30G   45M   28G   1% /newvolume
/dev/loop0       34M   34M     0 100% /snap/amazon-ssm-agent/3552
/dev/loop1       56M   56M     0 100% /snap/core18/1988
/dev/loop2       70M   70M     0 100% /snap/lxd/19188
/dev/loop3       71M   71M     0 100% /snap/lxd/19647
/dev/loop4       32M   32M     0 100% /snap/snapd/11036
/dev/loop5       33M   33M     0 100% /snap/snapd/11107
tmpfs            98M     0   98M   0% /run/user/1000
tmpfs            10M     0   10M   0% /tmp
```

Comment: Run `df -iH` to see if your `/` partition have any free inodes

Comment: This give me this. here https://pastebin.com/7vg7aCLG

Comment: Is / mounted on xvda1 by any chance?